# How to set an offset regarding the current post?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been trying to achieve the following result in my site:

The user is viewing **Post 5**, and I need that the "archive" in my sidebar (wich is just normal loop) shows the 3 previous posts. Respectively **Post 4**, **Post 3** and **Post 2**.

Then, if the user clicks in **Post 4**, for example, then the archive will show **Post 3**, **Post 2** and **Post 1**.

The logic then is: if current is post **X** I want the archive to show **X-1**, **X-2** and **X-3**

How can I achieve this ? The `offset` parameter will not work because it relates only with the most recent post.

Do ya have any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question to know how to do this without a plugin.  Unfortunately I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere online.  The way I currently am achieving this is by utilizing the plugin "List Category Posts" as the off set can be customized according to instance of short codes used.  the plugin allows it to be used multiple times on a sing page template.

The only fear is plugin and WP Core incompatibility in the future if plugin is not supported by the developer.

Hopefully someone knows how to accomplish a offset using php flexible enough to use with one loop without the need to create multiple loops.

Comment: Actually I managed to do this, using the database infrastructure of WP itself. But it still falls into the WP Core compatibility issue in the future.